# Join dataframe columns in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataframe called X

**X** has 3 columns (*Uni, Sub, Colours*)

Uni is string, Sub is string

but Colours is an **array** of strings

data in X look like this

```
Uni     Sub      Colours
-----   ------   -------
Melb    Math     (Red, Blue, Green)
Melb    English  (Yellow, Blue, Brown, White)
Sydney  Math     (Green, Pink, Red, White, Black)
Sydney  Art      (White, Pink)
Sydney  Med      (Yellow, Red, Pink, Brown, White, Black, Green)
Ottawa  Math     (Blue, Yellow)
Ottawa  Physics  (Red, Orange, Black)
```

I am trying to join these columns in one string so I can pass it to SQL Stored Procedure

my desired results should look like this

```
Melb;Math;Red, Blue, Green|Melb;English;Yellow, Blue, Brown, White|Sydney;Math;Green, Pink, Red, White, Black| ...
```

Where columns separated by a semicolon ; and rows separated by a bar |

I have this code

```
MyString = X[['Uni', 'Sub', 'Colours']].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x), axis = 1)
```

But I was getting this error

> TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, tuple found

So I changed it to this

```
X["Codes"] = ",".join(map(str, X["Codes"]))
MyString = X[['PtsID', 'VisitID', 'Codes']].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x), axis = 1)
```

but the end results are not what i want as it was a **list** and it look like this

```
Melb    Math     Red\n1    Blue\n2    Green\n3
Melb    English     Yellow\n1    Blue\n2    Brown\n3    White\n4
.
.
.
```

Any idea how can I get my desired format for a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [346]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Uni':['Melb', 'Melb', 'Sydney', 'Sydney'], 'Sub':['Math', 'English', 'Math', 'Art'], 'Colours':[('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'), ('Yellow', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'White'), ('Green', 'Pink', 'Red', 'White', 'Black'), ('White', 'Pink')]})
     ...: 

In [347]: df
Out[347]: 
      Uni      Sub                           Colours
0    Melb     Math                (Red, Blue, Green)
1    Melb  English      (Yellow, Blue, Brown, White)
2  Sydney     Math  (Green, Pink, Red, White, Black)
3  Sydney      Art                     (White, Pink)
```

Use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
In [350]: df.Colours = df.Colours.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))

In [352]: ans = df.agg(';'.join, 1).str.cat(sep='|')

In [353]: ans
Out[353]: 'Melb;Math;Red,Blue,Green|Melb;English;Yellow,Blue,Brown,White|Sydney;Math;Green,Pink,Red,White,Black|Sydney;Art;White,Pink'
```